# TableView inside ViewController but keeping inheritance /subclass system

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Here is the problem - the left image display how my Tableview was before filling the whole screen and the right the new one, that is a standard ViewController with a TableView inside. The trouble is in the new one I need to add a outlet to the tableview, set it as tableview/source delegate and then copy all the code from my TableviewControllers (which uses a series of subclasses for reusability). If I copy over all this to the ViewController then I end up copying a lot of code, and ruining my system of inheritance, perfect way to introduce bugs, and create a lot of extra work

Is there a way around this?

In the left image the controller class follows a hierarchy of inheritance

```
ThisTBC > abstractTBC ->UITableViewController
```

In the right image, the controller is a simple ViewController. But if I want to control the
TableView from this controller can I do it without having to copying all the code from the left controller (ThisTBC > abstractTBC) into the right ViewController

[image]

Comment: Maybe the real problem is that I´v put to much stuff into the ViewController that really should be in the model

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same code in two different classes, then why not abstracting this code into a new class? I am not exactly familiar with your code, but as an example I will provide this:

Imagine that you have 2 view controllers that do completely different things, however they are supposed to resize the same way and be able to respond to a certain touch event exactly the same. In this case I would create a SuperViewController (just an arbitrary name) and subclass mentioned 2 view controllers from this super class.

I hope this provides you with some help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understood that you need two different controllers : one is viewController and other is tableViewController.You want this to code cluster in a single file.

If this is the case you are doing, any touch performed on the tableViewCell will invoke the method in tableview controller.

Could you please specify what actually you want to control in tableview from view controller.Do you want to change the content of table on click of segment button in view controller? or something else? Any sample code would be helpful.